# Historical Chart with different distances between values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mschart

Hi I Would like to present a chart with different distances between values at my ASP.NET MVC 3 project. Therefore i am using Strings for xCords and floats for yCords:

```
public FileContentResult CreateChart()
{
    string[] xCords; float[] yCords;

    [... "fill xCords an yCords" ...]

    Chart bytes = new Chart(width: 800, height: 400)
        .AddSeries(

            chartType: "line",
            xValue: xCords,
            yValues: yCords
         );

    return File(bytes.GetBytes("png"), "image/png");
}
```

The problem is that there is the same distance between all values.
So you could nearly name it a bar chart than a dot plot:
I could imagine that the reason is the type string for x-values, but I don't know 
how to fix it?

**EDIT: How I produce the xCords when I change the type for xCords to DateTime:**

```
    xCords = new DateTime[stockAquires.Count];
    {
        foreach (StockAquire stockAquire in stockAquires)
        {
            xCords[stockAquires.IndexOf(stockAquire)] = stockAquire.RatingTime;
        }
    }
```

StockAquire includes as one property: RatingTime

stockAquires includes many entries with the type of StockAquire

Comment: Do you mean different distances between the dates in the x axis?

Comment: yes, this was what I have tried to explain!

Comment: Then why are xCords strings instead of DateTimes?

Comment: this produces an empty chart

Comment: Changing xCords to DateTime results in an empty chart? You should probably show us how you populate xCords then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use DateTime in the axis you need to do two things:

1. Set the data type of the axis to `DateTime`.
2. Convert the values in the series from `DateTime` to `double` using `ToOADate`.

So your date populating code becomes:

```
double[] xCords;

xCords = new double[stockAquires.Count];
{
    foreach (StockAquire stockAquire in stockAquires)
    {
        xCords[stockAquires.IndexOf(stockAquire)] = stockAquire.RatingTime.ToOADate();
    }
}
```

Then after you create the chart you need to explicitly set the data type for the x axis:

```
bytes.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

For more info see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456614.aspx).

Comment: Thanks so far, but I an error occured concering "bytes.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;"

Error: No definition for Series and ChartValueType
In addition I cannot include an using reference

Comment: I placed that line just in front of the last line in the first part of my description. (before the return function)

Comment: appears in the error list of ms visual studio while that line is red marked

Comment: yes, but what does the error *say*? "Object not found"? "Syntax Error"? ... etc.

Comment: Error 1 "System.Web.Helpers.Chart" contains no definition of "Series" and there could be found no extension method 'Series ", which accepts a first argument of type' System.Web.Helpers.Chart". (Missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 59 BetaImperium.Web D: \... ExchangeController.cs 19

Comment: Error 2 The name "Chart ValueType 'does not exist in the current context. 59 BetaImperium.Web D: ... ExchangeController.cs 42

Comment: Try putting this at the top of you don't already: `using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;`

Comment: Thank you, the reference on the right .dll was absent. I had to download and include them as you described